# Will FirstOrDefault remove the value from the BlockingCollection

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, task-parallel-library

```
    Dim logDetail = (
        From d In UIDLs
        Select d.EmailID
        Where EmailID = UIDL
    ).FirstOrDefault
```

The blocking collection is UIDLs.
Will the logDetail object get taken out of the blocking collection?

This is probably an invalid use of the blocking collection, but UIDLs is just there so I can do a parallel lookup of the values in UIDLs. I was considering using the concurrent dictionary, that seems even worse to me since i basically just have an array of objects and not name value pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this query will utilize the IEnumerable interface.

The blocking collection's default GetEnumerator will NOT remove items from the list.

[BlockingCollection.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267242.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`FirstOrDefault()` won't remove any items from the collection. If you used `GetConsumingEnumerable()`, then `FirstOrDefault()` would remove an item from the collection, but also all items before it, which is not what you want.

You're saying you just have an “array of strings”, but your code says something else: that you have a collection of objects and you want to perform lookups in that collection based on some property of that object. If that's the case, `ConcurrentDictionary` should fit your needs well. With it, your code would look something like:

```
' add item to the dictionary
Dim logDetails = New ConcurrentDictionary(Of String, LogDetail)
Dim d = …
logDetails.TryAdd(d.EmailID, d)

…

' try remove item from the dictionary
Dim emailID = …
Dim removed = logDetails.TryRemove(emailID, d)
```

Comment: oh yea, you're right, it is a bunch of objects. I wrote this code about 4 projects ago and just got some strange results so I wanted to make sure i didn't make a mistake with the container type. Edited OP.